# Is it possible to create object using two Generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I want to define instance variables using two Generics like below.

```
class Foo<S,T>{
     private S<T> Boo ;
     .
     .
}

public class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          Foo<ArrayList, String> foo = new Foo<ArrayList, String>();          

    }
}
```

But It doesn't work... Is it kinda wrong grammar? I really need to this kind of grammar.

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't `S` have a requirement of `T`, similar to `<S<T>>`??

Comment: @Zizouz212 My guess is the `private S<T> Boo`. He never specified a type `S` that has a type parameter

Comment: Oh,, really?..Actually, i'm trying to make Hashtable of which slot has data structure S. And each S consists of  nodes that have  T as a instance variables. I want to choose S,T type when creating HashTable. How can I do that, then?

Comment: Tip: the [existing HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/HashMap.java) supports two *generic type parameters*. You could look at the source for that..

Comment: But I have created my own hashtable, and I have to... : class MyHashTable<S,T>

Comment: You have a nonsensical `S<T>` (if it does have a purpose, make sure to explain it) which a normal HashMap does not have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need:

```
class Foo<S>{
     private S Boo ;
     .
     .
}

public class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          Foo<ArrayList<String>> foo = new Foo<ArrayList<String>>();          

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's what i want.

Comment: Btw, I made a class like this : class Slot<S,T> and it has object variable 'S member'. And in my constructor, Slot(T component), I define construction like this : this.member = S();. But it doesn't work. Can't i do this??

Comment: Yes, You can't do it,

Answer (score 7):

This is invalid syntax

```
S<T>
```

because for any `x<T>`, `x` must be a known class or interface type.

What you want is a container type and an element type. This is possible

```
class Foo<C extends Collection<E>, E>{
    private C boo;

...

Foo<ArrayList<String>, String> foo = new Foo<>();
```

Comment: What if C is a class that I made by myself?, I mean not 'ArrayList', but 'class Moo'

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because `ArrayList` has it's own parameter and when you don't specify it it will be treated as ArrayList.

So your code would be treated as `private ArrayList<Object><String>` which is invalid.

For cases like these you just specify `ArrayList<String>` and have your definition like this:

```
class Foo<S>{
     private S Boo ;
     .
     .
}

public class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          Foo<ArrayList, String> foo = new Foo<ArrayList<String>>();          

    }
}
```

If you want to place constraints on `T` and `S` you can do it this way:

```
class Foo<S extends Collection<T>, T extends Comparable<T>> {
     private S Boo;
}
```

But you can't do

```
class Foo<S<T>, T extends Comparable<T>> {
     private S Boo;
}
```